# in ASP.NET Add dynamic radiobutonlist inside a div which is inside a listview

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, listview, webforms

I have a listview that contains divs in rows. All divs have there own controls working. One div contains radiobuttonlist which is getting data source from codebehind. The data is populated but the radiobuttonlist is carried outside of the relevent div.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
<div id="riDiv" class="rightDiv" runat="server">
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvItemDetails" style="border:solid; border-color:blue; border-width:10px;">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <tr runat="server" id="itemplaceholder" class="TopboxDiv">

                        </tr>
                        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder2">

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                 </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <div class="TopboxDiv"> 
                        <asp:Literal ID="litItemDesc" Text='<%# ".." + Eval("item_description") %>' runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <div class="MidboxDivWrapper" runat="server">
                        <div class="leftTagDiv">
                            <div class="pc">Price</div>
                        </div>
                    <div id="middiv" class="MidboxDiv" runat="server">
                        <%--<div id="innerRadDiv">--%>
                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlMidBoxDiv" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Pink" BackColor="Aqua" style="z-index:2 !important;">
                            <span>
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdCrService" runat="server" DataTextField="ServiceName" DataValueField="ServiceName" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="radioDiv" >
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            </span>
                        </asp:Panel>

                        <%--</div>--%>
                        <div class="radioDiv">
                            <asp:RadioButton id="rdPost" Text="Postoffice Price" runat="server" CssClass="radiotext" GroupName="radPriceGroup" />
                            <asp:Literal ID="litPost" Text="Rs. 100" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <%--<div class="radioDiv">
                            <asp:RadioButton id="rdOCS" Text="OCS Price" runat="server" CssClass="radiotext" GroupName="radPriceGroup"/>
                            <asp:Literal ID="litOCS" Text="Rs. 110" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="radioDiv">
                            <asp:RadioButton id="rdTCS" Text="TCS Price" runat="server" CssClass="radiotext" GroupName="radPriceGroup"/>
                            <asp:Literal ID="litTCS" Text="Rs. 120" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="radioDiv">
                            <asp:RadioButton id="rdOther" Text="Other Price" runat="server" CssClass="radiotext" GroupName="radPriceGroup"/>
                            <asp:Literal ID="litOther" Text="Rs. 120" runat="server" />
                        </div>--%>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <div class="bottomDivItemWrapper">
                        <div class="leftTagDiv">
                            <div class="pc">Color</div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="bottomDivItem">
                        <div class="radioDiv">
                            <%--<asp:RadioButton ID="Rad1" Text='<%# Eval("ServiceName") %>' runat="server" GroupName="testGrp" CssClass="radiotext"/>--%>
                            <asp:RadioButton id="rdWhite" Text="white" runat="server" CssClass="radiotext" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="OrderDivWrapper">
                        add cart and wishlist buttons. write cart and wishlist code functions so it can be called again and again.
                    </div>                        
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please don't use the Visual Studio tag unless you have a question about the tool itself.

Comment: The problem wasn't very big. But I wonder why no body was interested to answer/solve it.

Comment: It would help if you clarified what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty contrived example, but it's possible to databind the Radio Button Lists too. Below is an example; it's admittedly rather contrived, but it works.

First, the code-behind (including how I'm constructing the list). The details of `getRandomString` and `getRandomListOfStrings` aren't all that important - basically, I'm just generating random data to populate the front-end with. Obviously, you'll want to replace this with whatever your *actual* data source is.

```
private class Temp
    {
        public string MainName { get; set; }

        // This is probably the key point here - I create a property to
        // hold data to bind my radio buttons to
        public List<string> RadioButtonOptions { get; set; }
    }

    private string getRandomString(Random r)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        int length = r.Next(3, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int chr = r.Next(0, 60);
            char result = (char)(33 + chr);

            sb.Append(result);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private List<string> getRandomListOfStrings(Random r)
    {
        int listLength = r.Next(3, 6);

        var list = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++)
        {
            list.Add(getRandomString(r));
        }

        return list;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        var list = new List<Temp>
        {
            new Temp
            {
                MainName = getRandomString(r),
                RadioButtonOptions = getRandomListOfStrings(r)
            },
            new Temp
            {
                MainName = getRandomString(r),
                RadioButtonOptions = getRandomListOfStrings(r)
            },
            new Temp
            {
                MainName = getRandomString(r),
                RadioButtonOptions = getRandomListOfStrings(r)
            },
            new Temp
            {
                MainName = getRandomString(r),
                RadioButtonOptions = getRandomListOfStrings(r)
            },
            new Temp
            {
                MainName = getRandomString(r),
                RadioButtonOptions = getRandomListOfStrings(r)
            },
            new Temp
            {
                MainName = getRandomString(r),
                RadioButtonOptions = getRandomListOfStrings(r)
            },
            new Temp
            {
                MainName = getRandomString(r),
                RadioButtonOptions = getRandomListOfStrings(r)
            }
        };

        mainListView.DataSource = list;
        mainListView.DataBind();
```

And the front end code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="mainListView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MainName") %>' /><br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("RadioButtonOptions") %>'/><br />
        <hr />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The HTML for the radio buttons looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><input id="mainListView_ctl01_1_0_1" type="radio" name="mainListView$ctrl1$ctl01" value="6U(" /><label for="mainListView_ctl01_1_0_1">6U(</label></td>
</tr>
```

And the front end looks something like this:

[image]